# Nested Attributes in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

i want to create comments in ruby but i have problem

1) posts_controller.rb

```
  def comment
      Post.find(params[:id]).comments.create(params[:comment])
      flash[:notice] = "Added your comment"
      redirect_to :action => "show", :id => params[:id]
   end
```

2)show.html.erb

```
  <%= form_tag :action => "comment", :id => @post  %>
  <%= text_area  "comment", "message" %><br />
  <%= submit_tag "Comment" %>
  </form>
```

3)post.rb

```
class Post  
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
include Mongoid::Timestamps::Updated
field :title, type: String
field :content, type: String
field :user_id, type: Integer
field :tag, type: String
field :owner, type: String 

embeds_many :comments
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments


end
```

4) comment.rb

```
class Comment
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
include Mongoid::Timestamps::Updated

field :owner, type: String
field :message, type: String
field :voteup, type: Integer
field :votedown, type: Integer



embedded_in :post
end
```

i used mongoid

when i run server have problem

Routing Error

```
No route matches {:action=>"comment", :id=>#<Post _id: 5272289165af50d84d000001,           created_at: 2013-10-31 09:53:21 UTC, updated_at: 2013-10-31 09:53:21 UTC, title: "firstpost", content: "ronaldo && bale", user_id: nil, tag: nil, owner: "boss_dongdoy@kuy.com">, :controller=>"posts"}
```

Comment: can you post your routes here

Comment: i have no comment routes i have simple post routes

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
<%= form_tag :action => "comment", :controller => "posts" do %>
  <%= text_area  "comment", "message" %><br />
  <%= submit_tag "Comment" %>
<% end %>
```

Or I would try something with `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :comments do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_area :message %><br />
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Comment" %>
<% end %>
```

To use fields for you have to populate comments in @post object, you can do it in view or controller:

## View

```
<% @post.comments.build %>
```

or inline:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :comments, @post.comments.build do |c| %>
```

## Controller

In the action that is rendering the form:

```
@post.comments.build
```

If your record is not saving, you probably need to add attr_accessible in model:

```
class Post
  attr_accessible :comments_attributes
```